# Why are other assemblies rebuilt when a referenced assembly is modified?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, dependency-management, solution

I have a base assembly called `Company.Base.dll`.

It's been used in some other projects. For example I have used it in `ProjectOne.dll`.

However, when I change a class inside this `Company.Base.dll`, say add a method to one of its classes, I see that `ProjectOne.dll` is also changed after build. Why is it so?

Here are the steps I take:

1. Add a method to a class of `Company.Base.dll`
2. Build `Company.Base.dll`
3. Build `ProjectOne.dll`
4. Compare the new dll of `ProjectOne` with its old dll, and I see it's changed.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

That’s because when you build one project that is a dependency/reference on another project, the builded file (e.g. ref.dll) by default is copied to the main bin project folder and not builded in an unique project file. If you go to your main bin folder, you will see both files.
So if you make a modification on a dependency/reference project, this project need to be updated with the new binary content to work properly.
You can disable the local copy on dependencies/reference -> [reference project name] -> properties -> local copy
But unless you have some assembly resolver or something to work around it, you will only get a project that will not work properly because an un-updated reference.